# Java Convert UTC to Local time

Tags: java, date

I am saving Date using UTC time in the database below is sample code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application {

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        String timezone = "UTC";
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
        log.info("Timezone {} is setup as default", timezone);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DmDexApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

As expected Date is saved with - 2 hours in the database but now the issue is when I retrieve the date and try to convert it to local time I am getting challenges on this implementation

I have added the below implementation where I am using my timezone which is "Europe/Berlin" and it's +1 hours which means if I posted an incident at "*2023-11-01T14:00:02.038Z*" it will be saved in the database as "2023-11-01T12:00:02.038Z". I am sending an email and since my current time zone is +1 hour Date is "*2023-11-01T13:00:02.038Z*" instead of *2023-11-01T14:00:02.038Z* below is my code I added

```
public static LocalDateTime convertInTimeZone(Date date, ZoneId timezone) {
        if (timezone == null) {
            return date.toInstant().atZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()).toLocalDateTime();
        }
        return date.toInstant().atZone(timezone).toLocalDateTime();
    }
```

timezone is "Europe/Berlin"

Comment: So you want everything to be in "Europe/Berlin" timezone ? Why not just translate each datetime into that timezone, although I always question making code-bases time-zone-aware

Comment: Your question is unclear. On nov 1st, `Europe/Berlin` is +1 hour, so why are you saying "if I posted an incident at "2023-11-01T14" it will be saved as "2023-11-01T12"? That makes no sense. It is correct that `2023-11-01T12 UTC` is turned into `2023-11-01T13 Berlin`. So, given that this is all correct, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Do you understand that the `Z` on the end of `2023-11-01T13:00:02.038Z` means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds (“Zulu” time)?

Comment: What database engine? What is data type of your column?

Comment: @BasilBourque it is PostgreSQL and the data type is timestamp

`created timestamp(6) without time zone,`

Comment: @rzwitserloot, maybe you missed a point if I save an incident with this time `2023-11-01T14` it will be saved with minus 2 hours in the database since I am applying `UTC` for the timezone which means in the DB I will capture   `2023-11-01T12`.

Comment: Such details need to be posted as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Comment: @SiyamcelaNxuseka That is the wrong data type to store a moment, a specific point on the timeline. You need to change to a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Why are you converting it to LocalDateTime if you want it to represent a time in a particular time zone? It should be ZonedDateTime, or maybe Instant.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You are trying to record specific points on the timeline. But you are using the wrong data types for such work:

- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in Postgres database
- `LocalDateTime` in Java

It is no wonder that you are experiencing such a confusing mess.

To handle moments, you should instead be using:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in Postgres database
- In Java:

  - `OffsetDateTime` for JDBC
  - `Instant` for converting to/from legacy class `java.util.Date`
  - `ZonedDateTime` for adjusting into a time zone for presentation to the user.

I suggest you start by studying [the date-time tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) provided by Oracle free-of-cost.

## Details

> TimeZone.setDefault

Avoid setting, or even using, the JVM’s current default time zone. Doing so immediately affects all other code in all other threads of all apps running within that JVM.

> String timezone = "UTC";

Use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` provided to you in *java.time* framework.

> log.info("Timezone {} is setup as default", timezone);

Be aware that a split second later any other code in any other thread of any other app running within that JVM can change that default. So your logging that value is not necessarily helpful.

> As expected Date is saved with - 2 hours in the database

Really? Are you certain? What database engine? Do you understand that database access tools may lie to you, dynamically applying a default time zone as a well-intentioned but misguided anti-feature?

Some database engines such as Postgres use the zone or offset of an input to adjust to UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

Later, in a comment, you confirmed that you are using Postgres with a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. That is the wrong data type for your column. When recording a moment, a specific point on the timeline, your table column must be of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (*not* `WITHOUT`).

> public static LocalDateTime convertInTimeZone

Incorrect type there. A `LocaDateTime` lacks the concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type cannot be used to represent a moment, cannot be a specific point on the timeline.

In contrast, the legacy class `java.util.Date` does represent a moment. It represents a date with time-of-day as seen with an offset of zero.

Avoid using the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

When handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to a `java.time.Instant` object. Use new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

To store in a database via JDBC 4.2+, convert to an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write to database:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To present this moment to the user in a specific time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zTokyo ) ;
```

Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime` to generate localized text representing the value held in `ZonedDateTime` object.

Convert to `java.util.Date` only if absolutely required to interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

> `.toLocalDateTime()`

In calling that method you **discard vital information**: the time zone or offset-from-UTC. And you get **no benefit in return**. All you get is an inherently ambiguous date with time-of-day.

When tracking specific points on the timeline, there should be no use of `LocalDateTime`.

For example, I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` would be wise.